# Can users ask HOW something works if they do not understand it themselves?

Tags: discussion

May we ask about HOW something works (for an explanation to understand the code) - even if the code compiles successfully?

I know generalising is forbidden as questions should be on-point / on topic but whilst learning from the ground up there does come circumstances where one just does not understand how a piece of code works.

On '[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)' the following is said:

> Introduce the problem before you post any code...Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve

The word: **Problem** is mentioned 14 times on that page alone (excluding the one in the example), so even if our code is not proving a problem is it permissable to ask for help on *how* some code works?

Many thanks

Comment: Depends, if it seems like is a whole code block or a method I'd say no. If it was a specific part of code I'd consider it to be okay

Comment: You can ask questions like this, but you need to be *very careful*, as they often end up being too broad. If you cannot provide any context to narrow down the scope of your question, or you have no background knowledge in the area, then you will probably not be able to ask this in a reasonable way.

Comment: @CodyGray I see, so... we must have a generally good idea about what is going on, even if we do not understand it all. In a beginners circumstance (like mine) this is a hinderance.We are unable to Google how something is done the way it is done. What would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest that beginners buy a book or find some other type of tutorial. Stack Overflow questions only work for specific, narrowly-defined subjects. We cannot teach programming languages or other broad skills here.

Comment: Most of these questions come down to a *lack of research*...the answers alomost **always** can be found by looking elsewhere.

Comment: 'one just does not understand how a piece of code works' - well, that is one good reason for stepping through with a debugger, noting values at each step.